# How to use getUserMedia from TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'd like to call  [getUserMedia](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/) from TypeScript, something like:

```
 return  navigator.getUserMedia()
```

However, TypeScript's definition of Navigator (in lib.d.ts)  doesn't contain getUserMedia. 
How do I work around? Should I be modifying lib.d.ts?  Where do I make this change?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The current practice for this is to add to the interface, rather than edit the lib.d.ts file.

You can add to the interface in your TypeScript file and when the lib.d.ts is updated, the compiler will tell you that you no longer need it. I have put it extra white-space to make the different parts of the declaration easier to read and I've added a sample call below the interface.

```
interface Navigator {
    getUserMedia(
        options: { video?: boolean; audio?: boolean; }, 
        success: (stream: any) => void, 
        error?: (error: string) => void
        ) : void;
}
    
navigator.getUserMedia(
    {video: true, audio: true}, 
    function (stream) {  },
    function (error) {  }
);
```

I would make this change in the class that uses `getUserMedia`. And I would try to restrict all usages of `getUserMedia` to that class.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of changing the definition you can cast to an any object an call with arbitray parameters e.g:

```
    var n = <any>navigator;
    n.getUserMedia  = n.getUserMedia || n.webkitGetUserMedia || n.mozGetUserMedia || n.msGetUserMedia;
    return  n.getUserMedia({video: true, audio:true}, onSuccess, onFail);
```

Answer (score 9):

Importing type definitions has been [simplified with TypeScript 2.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/).

Install the webrtc definitions as a dev dependency with NPM

```
$ npm install —-save @types/webrtc
```

Once installed, use the reference directive at the top of the .ts file that works with getUserMedia:

```
/// <reference types="webrtc" />

const getUserMedia = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia ||
                     navigator.getUserMedia ||
                     navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                     navigator.mozGetUserMedia
```

That should do it!

Comment: there is no msGetUserMedia. Also navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia is promise-based while the legacy and deprecated navigator.getUserMedia is callback based.You largely don't need those shims anymore, just use navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia

Comment: @PhilippHancke You're correct about msGetUserMedia; deleted from example. Leftover from some junk code I had lying around. I agree that the shims aren't really necessary anymore, mostly pointing it out as an example.

Answer (score 4):

As this is already quite old but people might still come here looking for an answer, here is an updated answer using typings to manage all definitely typed files:

install typings, [Github Page](https://github.com/typings/typings), with these commands hacked into the command line (npm needs to be installed) and download mediastream.d.ts from there:

```
npm install typings --global
typings init
typings install mediastream --ambient --save
```

then either add the main.d.ts from the generated typings folder to your tsconfig.json file or add it directly to the typescript file you want it to use in with this line:

```
/// <reference path="typings/main.d.ts" />
```

Now typescript will recognize navigator.getUserMedia() and compile it correctly.
And the cool part about it is, that whenever you have another javascript lib (more or less well known) you need typescript to recognize you can just use typings and you will have it added in some seconds.

Comment: I had to use typings install dt~webrtc/mediastream -SG